# AngularJS Custom Directive Issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am fairly new to AngularJS and just came upon an issue while following a course (with an older version of Angular).
Having just created a custom directive, it does not appear to be called on the View side.
Here's my HTML code:

```
<h3>Results Found:</h3>
<div class="list-group">
    <search-result></search-result>
</div>
```

And here's the JS code:

```
myApp.directive('searchResult', function() {
    return {
        template: '<a href="#" class="list-group-item active"><h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Doe, John</h4><p class="list-group-item-text">555 Some St, New York, NY 101010</p></a>'
    }
});
```

Note: I am currently working with the **version 1.6.1** of AngularJS.
Would anyone be able to help me out?
(Thank you all in advance)

Comment: Is there a ng-app in your html?

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out Nicolas. Yes I have an ng-app right in the <html>. For some reason however, i restarted the text-editor and it now runs fine... don't get it. But once again thank you for your help Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('DirectiveApp', []);

myApp.controller("mainController", ["$scope", "$http",
  function($scope, $http) {
     
  }
]);
myApp.directive('searchResult', function() {
    return {
        template: '<a href="#" class="list-group-item active"><h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Doe, John</h4><p class="list-group-item-text">555 Some St, New York, NY 101010</p></a>'
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="DirectiveApp">
<head>
  <title>List</title>
  <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<div ng-controller="mainController">
  <div class="container">
    <search-result></search-result>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Sajeetharan. I restarted the text-editor and for whatever reason it all worked fine after all. But I looked at your code and discovered some things I did not know yet so will be lookibg at those as well. Thank you very much for your help!!